# Confusion over an example of weak limit in L2

Tags: functional-analysis

I understand the definition of weak limit, but I'm confused about the weak $L^2$ limit of the sequence $g_n = n1_{[0,1/n^2]}$.  The $L^2$-norm of each of these functions is $1$.  Does this mean the weak limit is the Dirac delta function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac delta function is not an object in $L^2[0,1]$. You have, for any $k\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$,
$$
\int_0^1g_n(t)\,t^k\,dm(t)=\frac1{k+1}\,\frac1{n^{2k+1}}\to0.
$$
This shows that $\int_0^1g_n\,p\to0$ for any polynomial $p$. Now, polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$, so a trivial application of Hölder lets you show that 
$$
\int_0^1g_n\,f\to0
$$
for all $f\in L^2[0,1]$. That is, $g_n\to0$ weakly.